# How to document both names and text in the same message with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Before i begin, i am brand new to python and I dont know much about coding in general, so im sorry if this is horrible.

Anyways, sorry if that sounds confusing, im trying to make an automatic real-time archiver, that displays both username, and the message that was sent. For example,

**Akasukioon - That is a nice looking pie.**

I will probably try to add more, like the channel it was sent in and the date, but for now this is a good start. But i need help. Heres my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot online ye')

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    async def on_message(message):
        if ctx.author.id != BOT_ID:
            await message.channel.send("{message.author.name}")
            await client.process_commands(message)
            await ctx.channel.send(" - " + ctx.content)
            await client.process_commands(ctx)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Its the best i could come up with after a couple of hours, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why did you add another function inside the `on_message` event? (Which should take `message` instead of `ctx`)

Comment: Im not at my pc currently, but if i remember correctly it needs to have ctx in there for the archive to function properly

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use an event in an event.

Second, `on_message` is called with a message object regardless if you are having the argument `ctx` or not.

Third, to your question, in Python > 3.6, using f-strings, it's simple:

```py
await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.name} said {message.content} in {message.channel} on {datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} at {datetime.today().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}") #f before the strings makes it to a f-string
```

for the date to work you would have to import `datetime` at the top of your script:

```py
from datetime import datetime
```

Your final `on_message` would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id != BOT_ID:
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.name} said {message.content} in {message.channel} on {message.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} at {message.created_at.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

---

References:

- [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)
- [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Comment: You can also use `message.created_at` instead of `datetime.today()`

Comment: `ctx` is not part of the `on_message` event. `if ctx.author.id` should spit out an error.

Comment: thank you! I wouldnt have been able to do it without you, i probably shouldve learned f strings before coding lol